# how to place youtube api to download videos?

Tags: api, video, youtube, download, youtube-api

I have seen plenty of websites offers to download videos using youtube api, i already searched for it but it seems its a bit complicated for me to understand how they are using it, If any developer is willing to help Me out i will be really thankful, its been almost a month im searching but no luck, i know stackoverflow is the only place to get my answer, please im not a pro so dont ask for the codes because i dont have any yet. I can provide links to these websites im willing to make, message me so we can talk on skype. thanx in adv

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube API doesn't allow downloading. Sites that offer downloads are using workarounds to get to those videos. If you need something that doesn't use the API take a look at [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) on Github.

Comment: thank you sir for quick response, but i may still need someone to help me out in setting up, i can pay for the effort. if you know any dev please let me know.